# WPF : Rounded-Corners Images

Tags: wpf, xaml, rounded-corners

```
<Page
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  Background="Black">
    <!-- Rounded yellow border -->
    <Border BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="Yellow" CornerRadius="10" Padding="2"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
      <Grid>
         <!-- Rounded mask (stretches to fill Grid) -->
         <Border Name="mask" Background="White" CornerRadius="7"/>
         <!-- Main content container -->
         <StackPanel>
             <!-- Use a VisualBrush of 'mask' as the opacity mask -->
             <StackPanel.OpacityMask>
                 <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=mask}"/>
             </StackPanel.OpacityMask>
             <!-- Any content -->
             <Image Source="http://chriscavanagh.files.wordpress.com/2006/12/chriss-blog-banner.jpg"/>
             <Rectangle Height="50" Fill="Red"/>
             <Rectangle Height="50" Fill="White"/>
             <Rectangle Height="50" Fill="Blue"/>
         </StackPanel>
      </Grid>
    </Border>
</Page>
```

This XAML is from [WPF – Easy rounded corners for anything](http://chriscavanagh.wordpress.com/2008/10/03/wpf-easy-rounded-corners-for-anything/) but it doesn't work form me =(

```
<Border Canvas.Left="55"
        Canvas.Top="30"
        Width="100"
        Height="Auto"
        Margin="12,12,8,0"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        BorderBrush="#FF3B5998"
        BorderThickness=".5"
        CornerRadius="18">
    <Border.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="5"
                          Opacity=".5"
                          ShadowDepth="3" />
    </Border.Effect>
    <Border Name="ReceiverColor"
            BorderBrush="#FF96B2E4"
            BorderThickness="6"
            CornerRadius="15">
        <Border Name="Mask"
                BorderBrush="#FF3B5998"
                BorderThickness=".5"
                CornerRadius="13">
                <StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel.OpacityMask>
                        <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=Mask}" />
                    </StackPanel.OpacityMask>
                    <Image Name="Receiver" />
                </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </Border>
</Border>
```

**--- EDIT ---**
I make borders sizes to auto and change source of image to an image from a link
when window loaded border size becomes as image size but image not shown !!!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You forgot the Grid that makes the mask and the image siblings and nested the image in the mask. and you forgot to set the background of the mask.

This works:

```
<Grid>
    <Border Canvas.Left="55"
            Canvas.Top="30"
            Width="100"
            Height="Auto"
            Margin="12,12,8,0"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            BorderBrush="#FF3B5998"
            BorderThickness=".5"
            CornerRadius="18">
        <Border.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="5"
                              Opacity=".5"
                              ShadowDepth="3" />
        </Border.Effect>
        <Border Name="ReceiverColor"
                BorderBrush="#FF96B2E4"
                BorderThickness="6"
                CornerRadius="15">
            <Grid>
                <Border Name="Mask"
                        Background="White"
                        BorderBrush="#FF3B5998"
                        BorderThickness=".5"
                        CornerRadius="13">
                </Border>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image Name="Receiver"
                           Source="/Images/test.jpg" />
                    <StackPanel.OpacityMask>
                        <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=Mask}" />
                    </StackPanel.OpacityMask>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Comment: No the first code is from the article but the second code is from my project

Answer (score 47):

You can define a `<Border/>` element and set its `<Border.Background/>` 
property to an `<ImageBrush/>` , set the Borders `CornerRadius` property and you 
are all set!

```
<Border CornerRadius="8,0,8,0">
    <Border.Background>
        <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="ImageSource"/>
    </Border.Background>
</Border>
```

Answer (score 12):

in wpf this one works for me

```
    <Ellipse Width="50" Height="50">
        <Ellipse.Fill>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="http://chriscavanagh.files.wordpress.com/2006/12/chriss-blog-banner.jpg" />
        </Ellipse.Fill>
     </Ellipse>
```

Comment: This solution doesn't give any control over the actual radius - and you lose control over the actual image.  It's in good solution if you need an Ellipse - but that is not the same thing as rounded corners like the questions asks.

Answer (score 6):

None of the above answers worked for me completely. I was trying to implement rounded corners on image which could be resized and has properties `Stretch="UniformToFill"` `VerticalAlignment="Center"` and `HorizontalAlignment="Center"`.
The center alignments keeps the middle part cropped as opposed to bottom and right side being cropped, when image is resized. Solutions with image brush were working but I was facing problem in keeping the content at center cropped.

The marked answer has a problem with transparent non rectangular images as the "mask" border will end up showing as white background. Following was the imlementation which worked for me:

```
<Grid>
    <WrapPanel Name ="container">
        <Image Source="sample_image.png" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
        <WrapPanel.OpacityMask>
            <VisualBrush >
                <VisualBrush.Visual>
                    <Border Height="{Binding ElementName=container, Path=ActualHeight}" 
                            Width="{Binding ElementName=container, Path=ActualWidth}"
                            Background="White" CornerRadius="15" />
                </VisualBrush.Visual>
            </VisualBrush>
        </WrapPanel.OpacityMask>
    </WrapPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: this solution allows to define maxwidth and maxheight.

Comment: Great solution!  Just one little thing, the outer Grid parent isn't required.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an ellipse like how Usman Ali has said (I thought this myself and I didn't take it from him)

It's very simple, make an ellipse with the properties you want, then set the fill to an imagebrush with your desired image like this in XAML:

```xml
<Ellipse Height="Auto" Width="100">
    <Ellipse.Fill>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="YOUR IMAGE SOURCE/LINK HERE"/>
    </Ellipse.Fill>
</Ellipse>
```

In C#, if in any case you want to do in C#:

```cs
Ellipse YourEllipseName = new Ellipse
{
    Height = 50,
    Width = 50,
    StrokeThickness = 0,
    Fill = new ImageBrush
    {
        Stretch = Stretch.Uniform,
        ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("YOUR IMAGE SOURCE HERE"))
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<Grid Background="Black">
<Rectangle RadiusX="20" RadiusY="20"
Width="130"
Height="130">
<Rectangle.Fill>
<ImageBrush x:Name="myImage" ImageSource="C:\Path\Desktop\visual-studio-2010-logo.png"/>
</Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.